# Kotlin compiler nullability check

Tags: kotlin

I'm a kotlin newby and wondering why the kotlin compiler does not recognize that my variable is never going to be null and how to get around it the nicest way possible.

```
var myString: String? = null
val myList = mutableListOf<String>()
for (element in 1..2) {
   if(myString == null) {
       myString = if(*somecondition*) "a" else "b"
   }
   //compiler error, cannot infer type String? to String
   myList.add(myString)      
}
```

A little explaination and how to handle those cases the best way would be nice!

Comment: You can just tell the compiler it would never be null by making it `myList.add(myString!!)`

The !! operator tells the compiler that even though the type is nullable, the programmer is sure that the value will not be null in this particular place, and so the null check should be performed and NPE thrown if null value is found.

Comment: @Rickky13 Thanks - I know that I can do this. I also know that !! should not really be used since the compiler usually infer wether something is null or not when it's that obvious.

Comment: another thread could have changed the value to null. Not in this particular case, true, but there is no way for the compiler to know that. But the real question is, why is it nullable in the first place? Just initialise it as an empty string and use that as the first check. Or you could also not even initialise it, and use reflection to check if it is initialised instead of checking if it is null (I would definitely not recommend this, but it is an option).

Comment: How about `val toAdd = myString ?: if (*somecondition*) "a" else "b";
myString = toAdd;
myList.add(toAdd)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to the newest compiler version the code mentioned in the question compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Because `String?` and `String` are two different types of variable (or constant). The value of your variable by the time of accessing it might have been changed by another thread/coroutine. In your case i would do something like:

```
var myString: String? = null
val myList = mutableListOf<String>()
for (element in 1..2) {
   myList.add(myString ?: if (/* condition */) "a" else "b")      
}
```